# programmatically creating a .pfx file

Tags: c#, pfx

Is there a way to programmatically creating .pfx file certificate? I would like to use it to sign PDF.  I would get the data of client from database then construct the file so when they click sign pdf, it would go out and get the pfx file that has been constructed and stored in database and then sign pdf with that file. so my goal is how to create the file? I am using C# 4.0.

Comment: do you want  to integrate the generated certificate with an existing PKI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ChilKat library. You will need the PEM file though, here is the link: http://www.example-code.com/csharp/pfx_fromPem.asp