# How to sign a text file with a certificate in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate

I have a plain text file with some contents, i need to sign this text file with a certificate (pfx file with password) and pass the document. On the receiver end thy will verify the file with the public key of this certificate. Please help with samples or procedures to sign the file.

Comment: Have you seen this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802311/programmatically-creating-a-pfx-file

Comment: i have the .pfx file and password. just want to sign the document using it..

Comment: something like [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/beginning-with-digital-signatures-in-.net-framework/), see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997118/how-do-i-sign-a-pdf-document-using-a-certificate-from-the-windows-cert-store) for more details maybe

Comment: May be this helps: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2008/06/25/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-signature-with-net-and-a-certificate-c/